# Swift2.3 で UNUserNotification (iOS10) のdelegateメソッドが呼ばれない

Tags: notification, swift3

Swift2.3で記述したUserNotificationコード(下記)でuserNotificationCenterが呼ばれません。
基本的に同等(と思われる)Swift3では動作します。基本的というのは、Swift2.3 と Swift3 でシンタックスが異なり、Xcodeの補完に従って変更しています。ここで誤っているのかもしれませんが、、、

```
import UIKit
import UserNotifications

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.

        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            // iOS 10
            let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.currentNotificationCenter()

            center.requestAuthorizationWithOptions([.Badge, .Sound, .Alert], completionHandler: { (granted, error) in
                if error != nil {
                    return
                }

                if granted {
                    debugPrint("通知許可")

                    center.delegate = self

                    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
                    content.title = "Title"
                    content.subtitle = "Subtitle" // 新登場！
                    content.body = "Body"
                    content.sound = UNNotificationSound.defaultSound()

                    // 5秒後に発火
                    let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 5, repeats: false)
                    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "FiveSecond",
                                                        content: content,
                                                        trigger: trigger)

                    // ローカル通知予約
                    center.addNotificationRequest(request, withCompletionHandler: nil)

                    center.getPendingNotificationRequestsWithCompletionHandler { (requests: [UNNotificationRequest]) in
                        print(">>>>> \(requests)")
                    }

                } else {
                    debugPrint("通知拒否")
                }
            })

        } else {
            // <= iOS 9
//            let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Badge, .Sound, .Alert], categories: nil)
//            UIApplication.shared.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        }

        return true
    }

    @available(iOS 10.0, *)
    func userNotificationCenter(center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                willPresent notification: UNNotification,
                                withCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {

        // ...
        let identifier = notification.request.identifier
        debugPrint("userNotificationCenter \(identifier)")
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

正直言うと「なぜこれから作るiOS10対応のアプリをSwift2.3で書くんだろう?」というところです。(もちろんSwift2対応の既存資産が大量にあるのでしょうが…。)
　AppleはiOS10のAPIについてSwift2対応のドキュメントを出す予定はありませんし、Xcode8では新規プロジェクトのテンプレートも用意されておらず、エディター上でのサポートも極めて限定的にしか働きません。
　たとえ、コンパイラーの設定をSwift2(Legacy)にしてあったとしても、Xcodeが提示したサジェスチョンは「Swift3用のものである可能性が高い」と思っていてください。

そう言うわけですから、もしあなたがSwift2.3での開発を続けるのであれば、あてになるのはXcodeでも、Swift用のドキュメントでもなく、Objective-C用のドキュメントだけ、ということになります。

あなたが実装しようとしているメソッドは、Objective-Cでは以下のような定義になっています。

[userNotificationCenter:willPresentNotification:withCompletionHandler:](https://developer.apple.com/reference/usernotifications/unusernotificationcenterdelegate/1649518-usernotificationcenter?language=objc)

> Declaration
>
> ```
> - (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center 
>        willPresentNotification:(UNNotification *)notification 
>          withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationPresentationOptions options))completionHandler;
> ```

これをSwift2流にimportしたらどうなるか、あなたはXcodeには頼れず自分で翻訳しないといけません。
　とりあえずこの例の場合のメソッドヘッダは、こうなるでしょう。

```
func userNotificationCenter(center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                            willPresentNotification notification: UNNotification,
                            withCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
```

お試し下さい。ただ、この部分が無事に動くようになったとしても、この先を考えると大変ですね。ネット上の情報などを見てもSwift3への移行に関する情報は急速に充実してきています。既存資産があれば、大変な作業であることはわかっているのですが、いずれやらなければいけないことですし、(特に新規にコーディングが必要な部分がそれなりにあるのであれば)早めにSwift3への移行を検討された方が良いように思われます。

Comment: 動作しました。ありがとうございました。全面Swift3化は仰る通りと思いますので、検討してみます。

Comment: @THo さん、ご報告ありがとうございます。Swift3への移行については、簡単に書いてしまいましたが、「大変な作業」であるのは間違いありません。似たような機能を持つSwift2のサンプルコードを何本かSwift3に移行してみて、作業量など十分に見積もった上で取り掛かられた方が良いでしょう。私の感触ですとXcode 8 beta 4のmigratorは(おそらくSwiftの変化の速さについていけず)変換の取りこぼしがかなりあるようです。安定するまで開発の手を止めるわけにもいかないでしょうから、難しい選択ではあると思います。良い選択をして良いアプリになりますよう祈っております。